# Validate textbox and radio button in jquery not working

Tags: jquery

i'm making a form, it includes 2 elements that is textbox and another one is 2 radio buttons.

I want to validate that user filled textbox and select one of radio button then the submit button will available. i validate with textbox keyup is fine, but i can not check for the radio buttons....

Here is my html code:

```js
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addbtn').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#addname').keyup(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '' && $('#addstt').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#addbtn').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#addbtn').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nametl">Tên thể loại:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="addname" ng-model="addName" class="form-control" name="nametl" placeholder="Nhập tên thể loại">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Trạng thái:</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline ml-1 mr-3"><input type="radio" ng-model="addstt" value="0" id="addstt" name="stt"><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger pl-1"></i></label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="addstt" id="addstt" value="1" name="stt"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success pl-1"></i></label>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <button type="button" id="addbtn" ng-click="addtheloai()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success text-white mr-2"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Thêm</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning text-white mr-2"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Two elements may not have the same id, as your radio buttons do. Use the `name` attribute instead. See also [How can I know which radio button is selected via jQuery?](//stackoverflow.com/q/596351)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change()`:

```
$("input[name='stt']:radio").change(validate)
```

Also, notice the selector is matching the elements by `name` (and `:radio`), not by id. You have **`id="addstt"` twice** in your code, which is invalid HTML (you shouldn't have duplicated ids.

Also, I have extracted the validation logic into a function called `validate`, so you could reuse it in both changing events:

```
$('#addname').keyup(validate);
$("input[name='stt']:radio").change(validate)
```

Full demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addbtn').prop('disabled', true);
  function validate() {
    if ($('#addname').val() != '' && $("input[name='stt']:radio").is(':checked')) {
      $('#addbtn').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#addbtn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
  $('#addname').keyup(validate);
  $("input[name='stt']:radio").change(validate)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nametl">Tên thể loại:</label>
    <input type="text" id="addname" ng-model="addName" class="form-control" name="nametl" placeholder="Nhập tên thể loại">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Trạng thái:</label>
    <label class="radio-inline ml-1 mr-3"><input type="radio" ng-model="addstt" value="0" id="addstt" name="stt"><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger pl-1"></i></label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="addstt" id="addstt" value="1" name="stt"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success pl-1"></i></label>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="button" id="addbtn" ng-click="addtheloai()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success text-white mr-2"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Thêm</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning text-white mr-2"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```